# signalr cant find the hub

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a very strange problem with the code which has not written by me but i need to get it run,i just started to learn signal,the problem is the application i cant run it on the local pc giving an error stating the hub is not found,but this application is running on the server!there is class which name is StatusMessageHubProxy which is below:

```
 public class StatusMessageHubProxy
{
    private static HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatusMessageHubURL"]);
    private static IHubProxy statusMessageHub = connection.CreateHubProxy(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatusMessageHubName"]);


    private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    /// <summary>
    /// Send update to status message hub so that all clients can update.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">ID of the turbine which sent the status change event.</param>
    public static void Update(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    logger.ErrorFormat("Could not connect to hub {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException(), connection.Url);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
                    {
                        // Invoke update method on hub
                        statusMessageHub.Invoke("Update", data).ContinueWith(invokeTask =>
                        {
                            if (invokeTask.IsFaulted)
                            {
                                logger.Error("Error invoking update method on hub.", invokeTask.Exception.GetBaseException());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Error("Connection was not open, could not invoke method on hub.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error("Error sending update to status message hub.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

in the webconfig i have this:

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="StatusMessageHubURL" value="http//localhost/appname/signalr/hubs"/>
<add key="StatusMessageHubName" value="statusMessageHub"/>
```

here in view i have the error :

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done()
```

there is no hub in the connection thats why it throws me an error,any idea?

Comment: are you sure your url is valid?

Comment: @WojtekT on the local iis which url i should write?

Comment: Well first of all you have a type in your url You are missing `:`  arfter http `http//localhost/appname/signalr/hubs`

Comment: @WojtekT corrected but still the same issue

Comment: in the browser i see error 500 for https://localhost:44301/signalr/hubs  @WojtekT